# I finished the Sovngarde quest. But I didn't get the shouts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Okay.

> So here's the story, I went in the portal, I defeated the guardian of the bridge, he tells me I can go back anytime with the shout... But I didn't get it.

Anyone know why not?

Comment: Forgot too put spoiler alert......

Comment: Added the spoiler tag. FYI it's >! before the line.

Answer (score 2):

You do not get a shout to go back. Instead,

> Go inside the hall, talk to some people, come back out, and kill Alduin once and for all, if you haven't done those things yet.

You will then be given a shout that summons allies, and the guy guarding the bridge will himself shout you back home.

If you have done all of that, and it's that summoning shout you're missing, then you have most likely run into yet another of Skyrim's near-infinite bugs. As with almost all of them, there are PC console commands that can work around the issue, as well as the Unofficial Skyrim Patch. If you're on a console, you can try reloading an older save and doing it again.